How should I show that $x_{0}(\tau)$ and $x_{1}(\tau)$ satisfy the given equations?
Homework problem: Consider the differential equation (which is a modified van der Pol equation) $\ddot{x}+\epsilon(x^4-1)\dot{x}+x+\epsilon\alpha^2 x^3=0, x(0)=a>0, \dot{x}(0)=0, 0\leq\epsilon<<1$, where $a$ and $\alpha$ are constants. Apply the Lindstedt method with expansion $x(\tau)=x_{0}(\tau)+\epsilon x_{1}(\tau)+O(\epsilon^2), \tau=\omega t, \omega=1+\omega_{1}\epsilon+O(\epsilon^2)$, and initial conditions $x_{k}(0)=a_{k}$ and $x_{k}'(0)=0$ for $k=0, 1, 2, ...$ (where the prime represents differentiation with respect to $\tau$, and the $a_{k}$ are constants) to show that $x_{0}(\tau)$ and $x_{1}(\tau)$ satisfy the equations $\frac{d^2x_{0}}{d\tau^2}+x_{0}=0, \frac{d^2x_{1}}{d\tau^2}+x_{1}=-2\omega_{1}\frac{d^2x_{0}}{d\tau^2}+(1-x_{0}^4)\frac{dx_{0}}{d\tau}-\alpha^2x_{0}^3$.
Here's my work: Proof:
By using the chain rule, we have $\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{dx}{d\tau}\cdot\frac{d\tau}{dt}$ for $\frac{d\tau}{dt}=\omega$ because $\tau=\omega t$, so we get $\frac{dx}{dt}=\omega\frac{dx}{d\tau}$.
Similarly, we get $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=\frac{d}{dt}(\omega\frac{dx}{d\tau})\implies \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=(\frac{d\tau}{dt}\cdot\frac{d}{d\tau})(\omega\frac{dx}{d\tau})\implies \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=(\omega\frac{d}{d\tau})(\omega\frac{dx}{d\tau})\implies \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=\omega^2\frac{d^2x}{d\tau^2}$.
With these substitutions, we obtain $\omega^2\frac{d^2x}{d\tau^2}+\epsilon(x^4-1)\omega\frac{dx}{d\tau}+x+\epsilon\alpha^2 x^3=0$.
From the work/proof shown above, what should I do next and proceed? Do I use the substitution of $\omega=1+\omega_{1}\epsilon+O(\epsilon^2)$ into this transformed equation? What should $\omega^2$ be then?

You insert $x$ and $ω$, that is, their $ϵ$ expansions. You are only interested in the lowest powers of $ϵ$, so you can omit a lot of terms when writing it down and expanding.

So I've got $(1+\omega_{1}^2\epsilon^2+2\omega_{1}\epsilon+O(\epsilon^2))\frac{d^2x}{d\tau^2}+\epsilon(x_{0}(\tau)+\epsilon x_{1}(\tau)+O(\epsilon^2))^4-1\frac{dx}{d\tau}+(x_{0}(\tau)+\epsilon x_{1}(\tau)+O(\epsilon^2))+\epsilon\alpha^2[(x_{0}(\tau)+\epsilon x_{1}(\tau)+O(\epsilon^2))]=0.$  Is this correct? How should I proceed from here? Do I keep expanding/distributing?

You also have to expand $\frac{dx}{d\tau}$ and $\frac{d^2x}{d\tau^2}$.

Is it $\frac{dx}{d\tau}=\frac{dx_{0}}{d\tau}+\epsilon\frac{dx_{1}}{d\tau}+O(\epsilon^2)$ and $\frac{d^2x}{d\tau^2}=\frac{d^2x_{0}}{d\tau^2}+\epsilon\frac{d^2x_{1}}{d\tau^2}+O(\epsilon^2)$?

I've got it now! Many thanks to Lutz Lehmann and Goncalo for the help!
